# jnlp console statements redirecting to server

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

we have so many println statements in our jnlp application, actually those are printing in client machines (C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\log). my question is how to redirect these statements to server side?

Comment: A JWS app. runs on the client side, so you'd need to write functionality to send that info. to the server.  That is a matter that is 'too broad' for SO. Note that 'printing in client machines' should be replaced with some form of logging.  Perhaps there are even logging APIs that will help in transferring info. to the server, but that seems a little outside the scope of logging in general.

Comment: HI,thanks a lot for your help.   1. can u suggest us atleast one API which will do this favor   "Perhaps there are even logging APIs that will help in transferring info. to the server 2. That is a matter that is 'too broad' for SO means for SOP statements?

Answer (score 1):

we need to open a socket from desktop application to server and then we have to post the messages to server. I searched for alternative way and could not find.

bottomline: system.out.println statements in desktop applications can not be redirected to the server .